# electron-forge make won't build

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-forge

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:

```
Error: Cannot make for rpm, the following external binaries need to be installed: rpmbuild
    at MakerRpm.ensureExternalBinariesExist (/home/chris/repos/dvdplayer/node_modules/@electron-forge/maker-base/src/Maker.ts:147:13)
    at _default (/usr/lib/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/src/api/make.ts:135:11)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/src/electron-forge-make.ts:44:5

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

I keep getting this error message when I run the command. Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 95):

I was able to fix this by running `sudo apt install rpm` in a terminal.

Comment: Same package name for Arch Linux through pacman

Comment: Why is this the most popular answer? Surely it would be better to simply not build the "rpm target" on a system that doesn't use RPM?

Comment: You may want to distribute the application.

Answer (score 17):

If you're running a Debian-derived Linux distro (eg. Ubuntu) you can run `sudo apt install rpm` to install `rpm`. Otherwise you must use your distribution's respective package manager to install `rpm`.